# Select multiple tables with same id

Tags: oracle11g

I need to select data from four tables based on only one.

In my **'calculated'** table, I have all the records I need.

But I need to retrieve some other info for each record, from **'programs'**, **'term'** and **'imported'** tables.

**'calculated'** has ID from **'programs'**.

But, to achieve a record from **'imported'**, I need to join the **'item'** table, because 'item' has ID from **'programs'** and from **'imported'**.

**'term'** has ID from **'imported'**.

So, I tried this:

```
select  c.date,
    p.name,
    c.name1,
    c.name2,
    t.date,
    i.version,
    c.price1,
    c.price2,
    c.price3
from calculated c, programs p, term t, imported i, item it
where c.programs_id = p.programs_id
    and c.programs_id = it.programs_id
    and it.imported_id = i.imported_id
    and i.term_id = t.term_id;
```

But when I use count(*) on **'calculated'**, I get 30k of records, and from my select statement I get more than 130 millions of records.

What am I doing wrong?

What should I do for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all duplicates rows are equivalent, u can try smth like this

```
select  c.date,
    p.name,
    c.name1,
    c.name2,
    t.date,
    i.version,
    c.price1,
    c.price2,
    c.price3
from calculated c, programs p, term t, imported i
where c.programs_id = p.programs_id and
(select imported_id from item it where c.programs_id = it.programs_id and rownum = 1) = i.imported_id
and i.term_id = t.term_id;
```

where "rownum = 1" is restriction on the selection of one line for oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the help Koroed, but today I was told that's no longer needed use this sql statement. I was able then to retrieve the data successfully. Thank you all for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to join `term` table.

Probably you need to add

```
and t.term_id = i.term_id
```

Comment: Hi Cha, I had already corrected my sql statement. The `term` table was already joined to, but was with wrong alias.

Comment: OK, so in this case you probably have one-to-many relationship in some of your tables. E.g. first that comes to mind is that there are multiple items (table `item`) are imported in one batch (table `imported`). Try to exclude tables one by one to see which one causes the duplication

Comment: Thank you Cha. I found that the join between `calculated`and `item` causes the duplication. So, how do I fix this?